# Visual sourcesafe connection between virtual and build machine

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005, visual-sourcesafe-plugin

I have a problem and there are no lots of documents about that.
I will use visual studio as ide.

I want to use visual source safe for sharing and logging our projects from a server.

I installed source safe.But i have some help about how to connect this machine to our programmers machine.

I need detailed help about this because this is an unusual subject for me.
If there is someone to help we can do it by remote too.

Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to retrieve the files which your programmers stored in SourceSafe database? If so, you can use Open from Source Control command under File menu. [More details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165650.aspx)

You can also refer to the using VS with SourceSafe tutorial [here](http://www.kevingao.net/version-control/sourcesafe/using-sourcesafe-in-visual-studio-2005-2008.html).